# Suggestion for resolving time out error and optimizing each loop in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Currently I am facing a problem in which I am getting the **Timeout::Error**. Here is my detailed scenario

I have following  tables

1. clients
2. users - (contains client_id)
3. scheme_transactions - (contains user_id)

**Model - Client**

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :users
   has_many :scheme_transactions
end
```

**Model - User**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :scheme_transactions
end
```

**Model - SchemeTransaction**

```
class SchemeTransaction < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Consider an example, I have a client (stored in the clients table) say ABCL which has around 1000 users (stored in the users table) and there are around 50000 transactions (stored in the scheme_transactions table) done by all of the respective client users.

Now I have to find **total of the first transaction of each user**. For this I have written following logic and it is working fine on the rails console but getting Time out error in the browser.

```
users = User.joins(:client).where(clients: {id: clients})
first_purchase = Array.new
users.each do |user|
    user_transaction = SchemeTransaction.joins(:user).where(scheme_transactions: {user_id: user.id}).first
    first_purchase << user_transaction.points unless user_transaction.nil?
end
total_first_purchase = first_purchase.inject(:+)
```

So is there any other way to avoid the problem or how can I simplify my logic.

I am using ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.11

**EDIT**
Also tried using **find_each** method

```
users.find_each(:batch_size => 1000) do |user|
   user_transaction = SchemeTransaction.joins(:user).where(scheme_transactions: {user_id: user.id}).first
   first_purchase << user_transaction.points unless user_transaction.nil?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a SQL query:

```
SELECT SUM(points)
FROM scheme_transactions
WHERE id in (
    SELECT MIN(id)
    FROM scheme_transactions st
    INNER JOIN users u ON st.user_id = u.id
    WHERE u.client_id = :client_id
)
```

Your method will queries the database for each `User`, hence the timeout.

Comment: yes you are right about the query but it is giving me overall sum of points and I needed only first transaction sum.

Comment: I added `limit` and `order` calls.

Comment: I have already tried this type of logic but still it returns the overall sum.

Answer (score 0):

There are three joins here, each join will be using increasing amounts of memory. The third joins a 50000 row table to the result of clients * 1000 rows. Thats 50,000,000 x clients rows held in memory and temporary hard disk memory (page swaps are slow).

Retrieve just the users for this client

```
users = Client.find(client_id).users
```

In your users loop retrieve only the transaction you want by sorting and taking the first transaction. You may need to consider specifying DESC in the sort_by if you get the last transaction rather than the first.

```
user_transaction = user.scheme_transactions.sort_by(:date).first
```

Your models appear to be set up ok, so this should be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

If user model has client_id, I'm not sure why are using 'joins' in following query

```
 users = User.joins(:client).where(clients: {id: clients})
```

Why don't you use

```
 users = User.where(client_id: clients)
```

Second thing is in each loop, As scheme_transactions has user_id, you don't need use 'joins' for following query. Is following query working for you?, In rails 4.1.6 its not working for me.

```
user_transaction = SchemeTransaction.joins(:user).where(scheme_transactions: {user_id: user.id}).first
```

Simply replace this as

```
user_transaction = SchemeTransaction.where(user_id: user.id).first
```

Or

```
 user_transaction = user.scheme_transactions.first
```